# @ControllerAdvice pushes all available exceptions to response descriptions even if it can't be thrown

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I have a simple spring boot application with multiple `@RestController`'s and a global exception handler as a `@ControllerAdvice`, that handles few custom exceptions with custom codes and error dto. Also I'm generating api docs with swagger, and there is a strange behaviour:

Each method response descriptions contains all errors, described in `@ControllerAdvice` not depending whether method can throw this custom exception or not :)

For example, I have two rest controllers:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
class FooController(private val fooService: FooService) {

    fun makeFoo() {
        fooService.makeFoo()
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bar")
class BarController {

    fun makeBar(private val barService: BarService) {
        barService.makeBar()
    }
}
```

FooService can throw FooException and BarController can throw BarException.

I'm processing these errors via global exception handler:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(FooException::class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
    fun indexAlreadyExists(exception: FooException) {
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(BarException::class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    fun indexAlreadyExists(exception: BarException) {
    }
}
```

So, swagger `FooController` responses should contain 409 and `BarController` responses should contain 422. But they both contain 409 & 422 responses.

How can it be set up manually or maybe configured? I need the responses to be separate for each method as the current business logic is...

*p.s. seems like it's normal for a global `@RestControllerAdvice`, but I can't figure out a way to adjust it somehow to include only the proper responses...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I don't now if you already foud a solution, but it can help others. I solved it placing the option **@Hidden** from swagger (v3) in my class annoted with `@ControllerAdvice`. Everything annoted (method or class) is hidden from all Swagger endpoints. With this option you must mark everything you want to be mapped in the Swagger page in the classes/methods annotated with `@RestController`.

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Hidden;

@Hidden
```